# When do we need to use subl instruction during the stack initialization in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

So I saw stack initialization as following

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $constant, %esp
```

or just

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

Our professor said that we should not do subl instruction for %esp because it automatically decrements as we push stuff on the stack. So why then I see so many different examples of assembly when we use subl instruction? When does it make sense to use it and when doesn't?

Thank you

Comment: I believe there's some kind of micro optimization at play: Multiple pushes have to wait for one another, whereas the mov/sub instructions can be pipelined better. But that's mostly speculation and badly remembered fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `push` and `subl $K, %esp` will decrement `%esp` and thus reserve space on the stack. You can choose whichever you like - `push` will probably be easier to read - but you shouldn't do both.

If you intend to be store SIMD values on the stack it will be a little easier to ensure alignment is maintained with `subl`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstood what the instructor was trying to say. The instructor was trying to say "Don't write

```
subl $4, %esp /* reserve memory on the stack to save %ebx */
pushl %ebx    /* save %ebx on the stack */
```

because the `pushl` already includes a `subl $4, %esp` built into it."

In other words, `pushl %ebx` is roughly equivalent to

```
subl $4, %esp
movl %ebx, (%esp)
```

(Not exactly because of flags, but you get the idea.) Therefore, you don't need to do a `subl $4, %esp` because that is part of what `pushl` does. If you do your own `subl $4, %esp`, then you decremented `%esp` by eight, not four.

On the other hand, if you want to reserve memory on the stack for something other than pushing registers, then go ahead and use `subl`.

Answer (score 2):

The `sub` instruction following the stack frame setup reserves space on the stack for any local variables that are needed.

If you don't have stack-based locals but only use registers then you don't need it.

Comment: but I saw many Assembly code examples that do not actually do subl having local vars. We just push smth on stack and esp is being decremented. Do you mean that if we do not reserve stack space beforehand we can then have no space for our local variables?